# BOUNDFILLER with select statement

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

In an Oracle Control File, can I populate a BOUNDFILLER from a lookup table?

for example:

```
EMPID BOUNDFILER "SELECT EMPID from employees where refno=refno"
```

I tried but I get an error msg, I assume because this is not possible?

The error message is: Expecting valid column specification, "," or ")", found ....

Any ideas of how I can populate a BOUNDFILLER from a lookup table?

EDIT: Apparently I am not very clear in what the issue is.

I need the BOUDFILLER to be populated from a lookup table. When the value is coming from the source file everything works well.

Thank you.

Here are a few more lines of code to visualize what I am trying to do:

```
EMPID      BOUNDFILLER "(SELECT EMPID FROM table WHERE REFNO = :REFNBR)" (Trying to get empid from another table to use below)
EMPFIRSTNAME "(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM table WHERE TRANS = :TRANS AND FILENAME =:FILENAME)"
EMPLASTNAME  "(SELECT LAST_NAME FROM table WHERE TRANS = :TRANS AND FILENAME =:FILENAME)"
EMPEMAIL    "(SELECT EMPEMAIL FROM table WHERE EMPID = :EMPID)"
EMPSUPERVISORNAME   "(SELECT EMPSUPERVISORNAME FROM table WHERE EMPID = :EMPID)"
EMPHOMECITY      "(SELECT EMPHOMEOFFICECITY FROM table WHERE EMPID = :EMPID)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas of how I can populate a BOUNDFILLER from a lookup table?

You can't. (Despite the wording in the documentation kind of suggesting you should be able to; I think that's a doc bug and it should say something more like "Filler fields cannot be specified as part of another field specification's SQL string, because..." - and then the exception for `BOUNDFILELR` makes more sense).

If `EMPID` is not a field in your data file then you don't need a filler for it. If it is in the file but not in the target table you can skip it with a plain `FILLER`, unless you want to refer to that file value later too. If it is a column in your target table then you could use an `EXPRESSION` clause to do the look-up instead, but then you can't refer to that as a bind variable elsewhere.

If you want to refer to it in other SQL expressions for other columns in your control file then you'll need to repeat the lookup as a subquery in those.

For example, you could have:

```
REFNBR BOUNDFILLER,
EMPID EXPRESSION "(SELECT EMPID FROM lookuptable WHERE REFNBR = :REFNBR)",
EMPFIRSTNAME EXPRESSION "(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM anothertable WHERE empid = (SELECT EMPID FROM lookuptable WHERE REFNO = :REFNBR))",
...
```

or slightly with a join:

```
REFNBR BOUNDFILLER,
EMPID EXPRESSION "(SELECT EMPID FROM lookuptable WHERE REFNBR = :REFNBR)",
EMPFIRSTNAME EXPRESSION "(SELECT t1.FIRST_NAME FROM lookuptable t1 JOIN anothertable t2 ON t2.empid = t1.empid WHERE t1.REFNBR = :REFNBR)",
...
```

I've declared them as `EXPRESSION` on the assumption that they don't have corresponding fields in the data file - essentially for these purposes that the data file only has `REFNBR`. (You may have other fields you haven't shown; you may even have fields correspondng to `EMPID` etc that you ignore - but in that case I'd treat those as `FILLER` and have independent `EXPRESSION` entries anyway to make it clear they aren't related.)

---

What you can't do is either supply a SQL expression as part of a `BOUNDFILLER`, or refer to one `EXPRESSION` in another field's SQL expression, i.e.:

```
REFNBR BOUNDFILLER,
EMPID EXPRESSION "(SELECT EMPID FROM lookuptable WHERE REFNBR = :REFNBR)",
EMPFIRSTNAME EXPRESSION "(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM anothertable WHERE empid= :EMPID)",
...
```

as that will throw

> SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable EMPID in SQL string for column EMPFIRSTNAME.

The reason is kind of the same for both. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-5C36E962-A73D-4E1E-8696-73079CDE84EB):

> For each input record read, the value of the field referenced by the bind variable will be substituted for the bind variable.

It looks at the value of the field *from the file*, not after any transformation form a SQL expression. If you were only using `REFNBR` for that lookup then you might consider not referring to that directly at and doing:

```
EMPID "(SELECT EMPID FROM lookuptable WHERE REFNBR = :EMPID)",
EMPFIRSTNAME EXPRESSION "(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM anothertable WHERE empid= :EMPID)",
...
```

but in the `EXPRESSION` evaluation it's still using the original value of the value from the file - i.e. actually a `REFBNR` - and not the final value that will be inserted as `EMPID`. So won't find a match, or won't match the row you intended, which is probably worse.

Given that, it wouldn't make sense for `BOUNDFILLER` to allow an SQL expression to be used - the result of that expression would never be used.

---

A couple of other thoughts... Clearly repeating the subquery/join is messy, so I can see why a reusable modified value would be useful in this scenario. But since you can't do that, it would be simpler to load the raw `REFNBR` (and any other fields you need from the file) into a staging table - either physical or an external table as @Littlefoot suggested - and then query that and join to the other tables to do a final insert into your target table.

And it looks - from what may be a very contrived example - like you're duplicating data, which may not be sensible; it might be better to actually just have `REFNBR` or at least just `EMPID` in your target table instead with referential constraints, so any changes made in `anothertable` are reflected automatically when it's queried. This may be part of a larger process that archives and deletes, or something; but then it would still be simpler to use a staging/external table and drive that whole process off that, instead of trying to make SQL*Loader do some of that work.

Comment: I am so sorry if I was not clear, yes, I need to use a BOUNDFILLER as I need to use later on to pass it into more lookups.

Comment: I need the BOUDFILLER to populate from another table, but the select statement after it does not seem to be allowed.

Comment: And I am not sure why you modified my lookup table, the refno is another boundfiller from above and works as intended. The only difference is that the value is coming from the source file.

Comment: How have I modified the lookup table? Your question might be clearer with a fuller example. If you have several fields interacting then show that, with data and expected results. I'm still unclear why the first version isn't what you need.

Comment: I find it really clear. I need to fetch a value from a table and use that value in more queries below. Hence the column as bounfiller that gets its value from a table. Really don’t know how else to explain it.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this. I find your statement : If you want to refer to it in other SQL expressions for other columns in your control file then you'll need to repeat the lookup as a subquery in those.
very intriguing. Could you please elaborate?
I will try to add some more lines of code to my original question.

Comment: @AlexPoole That was brilliant using the subquery, not sure why I didn't think of it, I use in other cases. Maybe just needed another set of eyes on it. Be it as it may, you helped a great deal, thank you very much for that!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to switch to external table (behind the scene, it uses SQL*Loader). As it behaves as an "ordinary" table, you can write (PL/)SQL against it. It includes joins, subqueries, etc. so you'd be able to use that *lookup table*.

Comment: Could you elaborate please @Littlefoot ? How would that work processing 100s of files daily?

Comment: Who said anything about *hundreds of files*, until now? Anyway: external table is only one. Input file is only one (at a time, i.e. its name doesn't / shouldn't change). A new file overwrites the previous one. Select from the external table always fetches data from the most recent file. Do that as many times in a day as you want. I guess you have some *scheduling* enabled, or is it on demand? Doesn't matter, really - call the procedure (which utilizes the external table) the way you want.